# LESS: Permission denied error

Tags: less, web-essentials

I work in an environment where we have very limited permissions on our computer.  I installed Web Essentials 2012 and created a blank .less file.  The preview window is showing

```
/*

Compile Error.  See error list for details

*/
```

I pulled up the error list and it's showing

```
LESS: Permission denied
```

I can't find the error in any log or the event viewer so I don't know which account needs permissions to what folder.  I tried giving everyone all permissions to the folder that contains the .less file just to see if that was where the error is, but that didn't do it.  Does anybody know which folder it writes to?  The temp asp.net folder maybe?  Do you also know what account needs permissions?  I don't have rights to modify the temp asp folder, so I'd have to put in a request with my IT department, so I can't really just play around and figure it out via trial and error.

I've spent a few days trying to find an answer to this, but I'm not getting anywhere.  If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Comment: You can try checking out the workarounds described on this GitHub issue related to LESS files and Web Essentials: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1696 . I was able to workaround a similar issue to yours with a LESS file by adding the @charset "utf-8" line to it (described in linked to GitHub). Also, if you are able to you might try upgrading Web Essentials to 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after quite a bit of working on this it turns out that the cscript.exe process was being blocked by McAfee HIPS.